# How to define type of returned JSX element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'd like to use `JSX.Element` as property for another component. Something, like

```js
<ComponentA componentB={<ComponentB/>}/>
```

`ComponentB` contains another component with props

```js
const ComponentB: FC = () => (
    <ComponentC prop0={...} prop1={...}/>
);
```

So, can I set type for `componentB` that ensures, that it's will be a `JSX.Element`, that contains only one child with `ComponentCProps`?

Comment: Try `children: ReactElement<any & { someProp: 'toExtendsFrom' }>`

Comment: You mean `componentB: ReactElement<{ children: ReactElement<QuickLookProps> }>`? This way, if the `ComponentB` return `<div/>` typescript still allow it.

Comment: So `ComponentA` should accept a `componentB` property which must be an element with exactly one `ComponentC` child?

Comment: https://catchts.com/react-return-type

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, yes, exactly

Comment: I don't think you can do that -- or at least, **I** can't, but I'm not a TS whiz. I can't make it not accept an invalid `componentB` prop (which I find very surprising). It'll be interesting to see if I'm wrong. :-)

Comment: All JSX code is treated the same: https://tsplay.dev/4w1jGN  The only way to do this is by designing it such that `ComponentA` takes the other components as props and calls them itself.

Comment: Oh, sad news. The reason I would like to give the `JSX.Element`, is that `ComponentA` and `ComponentC` takes too much properties. But anyway, thank you all for the answering